# C++\Win32 API - Load controls at run-time from xml

Tags: c++, xml, winapi, controls, xrc

Is there a library that can load controls (buttons, text boxes, etc.) from an xml file? Kind of like in WPF.

Comment: In English, the combination operator is "/", U+002F SOLIDUS, not "\".

Comment: lol thanks for the correction... thats what I get for typing windows paths all day long :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt's resource files (*.qrc) are quite similar to XML (though they lack an XML header, so they're not truly proper XML). At least if memory serves, they get parsed and translated to C++ at build-time, so once the application is built, the UI is "fixed".

wxWidgets has an XML-based resource system (XRC, if memory serves) that I believe parses the XML and builds a UI from it at run-time. The UI can be modified independent of the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use GTKmm, then there is [GTKBuilder](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkBuilder.html) and [LibGlade](http://library.gnome.org/devel/libglade/stable/) (now deprecated). They get loaded at runtime and define a UI in XML.

Comment: There is a Windows version of GTKMm (http://live.gnome.org/gtkmm/MSWindows). It does come with a large set of dependent DLLs though.